# Octomap visualization doesn't display anything - rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation, visualization, octomap, octovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem as described here: http://answers.ros.org/question/53228/rgbdslam-cannot-produce-octomap/. However, when I execute `rostopic echo /rgbdslam/batch_clouds`, a long list of integers is outputted so I assume this is working. I don't understand why octomap viewer only contains an empty blue cube when I try to load the octomap I saved. How can I fix this?

Edit: I have attached a screenshot of the rxgraph: [image: Rxtgraph]

By the way, I get this output when saving the octomap, but I don't see `/octomap_binary` in the graph. Is that the issue?

```
rosrun octomap_server octomap_saver test2.bt
[ INFO] [1369321237.790118097]: Requesting the map from /octomap_binary...
[ INFO] [1369321237.809273887]: Map received, saving to test2.bt
```

Edit 2: I just found this topic: http://answers.ros.org/question/9965/how-to-get-octomap-to-store-data-sent-by-rgbdslam/. I downloaded Octomap using apt-get install; do I need another version?

Edit 3: This is the output I get from launching openni:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/depth/rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/disparity_depth/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth/min_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth_registered/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth_registered/min_range
 * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url
 * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id
 * /camera/driver/depth_registration
 * /camera/driver/device_id
 * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url
 * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /camera/depth/
    metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    points (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/rgb/
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/
    disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/ir/
    rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/depth_registered/
    metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [20137]
process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [20138]
process[camera/rgb/debayer-3]: started with pid [20166]
[ INFO] [1369429911.881946647]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
process[camera/rgb/rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [20203]
process[camera/rgb/rectify_color-5]: started with pid [20225]
process[camera/ir/rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [20280]
process[camera/depth/rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [20355]
process[camera/depth/metric_rect-8]: started with pid [20425]
process[camera/depth/metric-9]: started with pid [20459]
process[camera/depth/points-10]: started with pid [20515]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [20541]
process[camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth-12]: started with pid [20561]
process[camera/depth_registered/metric_rect-13]: started with pid [20621]
process[camera/depth_registered/metric-14]: started with pid [20647]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb-15]: started with pid [20667]
process[camera/disparity_depth-16]: started with pid [20728]
process[camera/disparity_depth_registered-17]: started with pid [20757]
process[camera_base_link-18]: started with pid [20815]
process[camera_base_link1-19]: started with pid [20834]
process[camera_base_link2-20]: started with pid [20852]
process[camera_base_link3-21]: started with pid [20907]
[ERROR] [1369429921.870903205]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1369429921.918984524]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1369429921.962493901]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
```

However, the GUI is listening to `/camera/rgb/image_rect_color and /camera/depth_registered/image_rect` which I don't see.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63273/octomap-visualization-doesn%27t-display-anything---rgbdslam/) by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 343 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It shows an empty cube when no data has been received. Check that the right topics are connected (rxgraph is a good tool for that) and that the tf frames are correctly set.

By the way: In the latest rgbdslam version you can save an octomap directly from the rgbdslam gui and do not need the external octomap server.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-23**:
Thanks for your reply! I have included a screenshot of the rgbdslam/octomap graph. It seems fine to me, isn't it?
How can I save the map directly as .bt or .ot? I just see .PCD, .PLY, .XML and .YAML in the GUI save options. Would that mean I don't have the latest version?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-05-24**:
In the latest version there is a gui option "Save Octomap". Get it from "ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam". It doesn't require starting an external octomap_server, as rgbdslam uses it as a library. This reduces a lot of interface problems, e.g. setting the right frames, dropped messages...

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-24**:
That's funny, I got my version from there a few days ago. I'll try again.
[Edit] I redownloaded it, and it's the same; no save octomap option.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-05-24**:
Are you positive you aren't confusing different versions? It's definitely in there. Check the source (e.g. search src/qt_gui.cpp for "Save Octomap"). See also http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/qt_gui.cpp

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-24**:
"Save octomap" is not in my qt_gui.cpp. I've downloaded the package with this command: svn co http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg. I'll just delete my entire package and try again. [Edit] Alright, that 3rd download did it! That was weird.

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-24**:
I have a new problem now; I get no output from the camera in the GUI. I think the topics might not be compatible, I'll post the list in my initial post. What do you think? I'm done for the week, I'll be back on Monday. Thanks a lot!!!

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-05-25**:
You can set the topics rgbdslam subscribes to in the launch file. See the existing ones for examples.

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-27**:
After a fresh restart, the problem has fixed itself. I can now see the images in the GUI as well as view the octomap with Octovis! Thank you so much for your help!!! I have another question for you, I will create a new topic in a few minutes.